# Unable to get value in Ajax response

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

The servlet which receives request  --

```
     Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
    LoginBean loginInfo = getInfo(userId,userPwd);
    //System.out.println("00000000-----------"+loginInfo.userId);
    JsonElement loginObj = gson.toJsonTree(loginInfo);
    if(loginInfo.getUserId() == "GUEST!"){

        myObj.addProperty("success", false);
    }
    else {

        myObj.addProperty("success", true);
    }
    myObj.add("login", loginObj);
    System.out.println(":::::"+myObj.get("success"));
    out.println(myObj.toString());
    out.close();
```

Here is the js file -----

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
script.onreadystatechange = callback;
script.onload = callback;
head.appendChild(script);
}
    loadScript("js/json2.js", myJSCode);
    var myJSCode = $(document).ready(function() {

$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
});


$("#login").click(function(e){


        dataString = $("#loginForm").serialize();


        var id = $("input#id").val(); 
        var pwd = $("input#pwd").val();
        dataString = "id=" + id + "&pwd="+pwd;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login",
            data: {
                id : id,
                pwd : pwd
            },

            dataType: "json",


            success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 if(data.success){
                     $("#ajaxResponse").html("");
                     $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Welcome</b> " + data.login.id + "<br>");
                     //alert("#ajaxResponse" + data.login.id);
                     alert(data['id']);   
                     alert(data['pwd']);

                 } 

                 else {
                     $("#ajaxResponse").html("<div><b>Login Credentials are invalid!</b></div>");
                 }
            } 
 });
```

I am getting the ajaxResponse if I am going with 1 element i.e 'id' but when I tried to get both the response I am getting value as undefined. I have tried with data.login.id & data[id] but unable to get desired output. Any help will be appreciated. Even I have tried with JSON.Stringify().

Comment: Can you add the raw response? There is no way to say what is wrong with your code if I cant see the response.

Comment: I am getting just 'undefined' in <div id="ajaxResponse"></div>

Comment: I know that, but what is  the value of data in ajax response?
The value that is passed in function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) ?
Add console.log(data) and in console window you can see it.

Comment: This is what I am getting in console  --                                                 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  login.js:52 
      $.ajax.success jquery.js:1075 
      jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:1193 
      jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:7538 
      done jquery.js:8324 
      jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback

Answer (score 1):

```
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login",
                data: {
                    id : id,
                    pwd : pwd
                },
...
```

This has data passed to ajax is not the same as the data in

```
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     if(data.success){
...
```

In this success callback data is response from the server and it has a different (or same structure) based on data that server returns to you.
if you want to print the value from ajax call, you need to use just id

```
$("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Welcome</b> " + id + "<br>");
```

I see you are trying to use "data.login.id" can you check what is real structure of data in response? add console.log(data) or put breakpoint that callback, or simple add debugger; code, it will stop code in that line for you without adding breakpoint.

Comment: can you manipulate my code in a way I understand what you want to say. Actually what I know is I am sending Json data from Servlet , this is why I used dataType: "json", in js. How I will retrieve the data send from servet as json. Getting a response directly as id is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex. I will give you +1 for the line

```
  $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Welcome</b> " + id + "<br>");
```

Though it is working when I use:

```
      data: {

                id: $('#id').val(),
                pwd: $('#pwd').val()
            },
```

Without changing my code to this one the line was not working. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: One part obviously I am not able to grasp is when I make a LoginBean and fetching the data as String. i.e data has a String value, I am getting the result using data.login.id , where login is the object of LoginBean, but in this case I am getting it directly. Any suggestion?